# How to send unique message in the BCC field of the email?

Tags: php, email

I am trying to establish a mechanize where the any email sent from my users to any person are also documented in a CRM system "if the sender choose to document the email in the CRM."

I can instruct the users to copy an email and drop it in the BCC field where the email will be sent to an email. Then I can take have a corn job that will read the email/parse it and add it to my CRM system.

However, there are two thing that I am unclear on how to do.

1. How can I send unique data in the email itself "not the body"? For example I will need to know what account_id, record_id to related it to after the email is sent. My first thought was to do a base 64 decoding to a jSON string and use that in the email address that being BCCed. But not sure if this works with the email standards.
2. How can my email server know to forward any email to a single email so I only have to read and parse email from one email?

I have seen this done in `SalesForce.com` where a user can BBC and email by using an email like this

```
`emailtosalesforce@v1hmxvru63wf2rqosh08jd7aw6sgv533qm0dbatsj396kjc8qad.d-ck84eae.na14.le.salesforce.com`
```

the part `v1hmxvru63wf2rqosh08jd7aw6sgv533qm0dbatsj396kjc8qad` contains data that relate the email message to a single record in the CRM using the account_id/ record_id values.

How can I do this using PHP?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
$a = array('account_id' => 123456789,
           'record_id' => 987654321);

$to = base64_encode(json_encode($a));

$toEmail = 'sentittoCRM@' . $to . 'sub_domain.example.com';
```

Comment: If you're already in control of sending the email, why can you not just save the relevant data into your database directly after sending the email?

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: @Populus the email are sent from a different application like Outlook they are not sending emails from the CRM.

Comment: @Andrey the 1 item is base64_encode generate a log email address and not sure if they email will be rejected the the server. second I am trying to figure our how to point all emails to one email

Comment: Those are 2 separate problems. 1) json is fat format, you can just do `base64_encode ('123456789_ 987654321')` 2) depends on your mail server and has nothing to do with php

Comment: I don't want to show the data in plain text I want to encode it somehow.

Comment: 1) Generate unique id for each `account_id` + `record_id` combination, use the unique id similar to your example of how salesforce does it. 2) You need to either have a custom email server receive the email, then parse the email for the data you need; or you have an external service connecting to your email server collecting emails and parsing it.

Comment: Just an additional comment. This is a non-trivial problem that you're trying to solve. Don't expect any simple or easy solutions.

Comment: @MikeA then encrypt it properly, all the rest is crap.